# Sort the Index in Sidebar in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using below script to create a Sidebar in a Google Sheet. This sidebar is an Index of all non-hidden tabs (sheets) in this spreadsheet

I would like this Index sorted alphabetically.

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar.html')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Index Sidebar');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getSheetNames() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  return sheetNamesIds(sheets);
}

function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true)indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
    
  });
  
  return indexOfSheets; 
}


function returnListItems(text) {
  
    var sheetNames = getSheetNames()
    
    // Checking if there is a search term
    if (text) {
      sheetNames = sheetNames.filter(n => n[0].includes(text))
    }
    
    var htmlString = sheetNames.map(function(d) {
        var string = `
        <li> 
          <input
           type="button"
           value="${d[0]}"
           onclick=\"google.script.run.setActiveByName('${d[0]}')\"/>
        </li>
        `
        return string }).join(' ')
    
    return htmlString
}

function setActiveByName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss)
}
```

Any ideas how to..?

Comment: HTML `<script>

function removeElement(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function buildList(text) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).returnListItems(text)
}
function onSuccess(result) {
    var element = document.createElement("ol")
    element.innerHTML = result
    var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")
    sidebar.appendChild(element)
}
`

Comment: Sort indexOfSheets by title using a compare function. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Cooper sorry am guessing it would go in Script file, unexptected identifier, means I need to assign values to `a` and `b` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to alphabetically sort the sheet names of the array from `getSheetNames()`.

  - From `I would like this Index sorted alphabetically.`, I thought that you want to achieve above.

In your case, I would like to propose the following modification for `sheetNamesIds()`.

#### From:

```
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true)indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
    
  });
  
  return indexOfSheets; 
}
```

#### To:

```
function sheetNamesIds(sheets) {
  
  var indexOfSheets = [];
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.isSheetHidden()!= true)indexOfSheets.push([sheet.getSheetName(),sheet.getSheetId()]);
    
  });
  
  indexOfSheets.sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1);  // Added

  return indexOfSheets;
}
```

- In this case, the sheet names are sorted with the ascending order.

#### Reference:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)